# MVC 4 - SessionStateItemCollection - Index was outside the bounds of the array - TempDataDictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications

We regularly get errors from within the MVC framework:

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array.    at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase.BaseRemove(String name)
   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Remove(String name)
   at System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper.Remove(String name)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SessionStateTempDataProvider.LoadTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Load(ControllerContext controllerContext, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PossiblyLoadTempData()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
```

Googling this error doesn't yield a lot of information...

In one part of the webapplication we set the sessionstate behavior to Readonly to increase the client side performance of loading multiple images. Due to some generic code we are also setting MVC tempdata in these requests. Could this be causing the error?

If so can this also cause the error to persist even if the user goes to other area's of the webapplication? (which is the case)
If not, what other possible causes could this error have?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the stack, it looks like TempData was used; TempData destroys session-state data after a redirect, so the next step was it's removing an entry from Session via `SessionStateItemCollection.Remove` (called to remove the session variable).  SessionStateItemCollection inherits from NameObjectCollectionBase, so that line item an ArrayList (inside that base class) are all internal operations.

Comment: I have the same issue but can't find the solution I'm using https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/session-state-behavior-per-action-in-Asp-Net-mvc/ please help me